# Why does the word "al-Ahmar" appear in the name of ibn al-Ahmar?

Tags: spain

[Muhammad I of Granada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_I_of_Granada), the founder the last Spanish Muslim kingdom, was also known by the name "Ibn al-Ahmar" ("son of al-Ahmar") The dynasty he founded, the Nasrid dynasty, was also known as "Banu al-Ahmar" ("children of al-Ahmar").

It seems that ''ahmar'' simply means "[red](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-arabic/red)" in Arabic. How did Muhammad I and the dynasty come to be associated with these names?

Comment: Did you mean _how_ or _why_ Muhammad of Granada was called _Ibn al-Ahmar_ or just simply, as asked, what does Ahmar mean?

Comment: @JAsia The how or why. I already found the meaning of the word itself. I clarified the question description

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that "*al Ahmar*" remains today a well known clan in Yemen.

Answer (score 3):

Muhammad ibn Yusuf ibn Nasr (1195–1273) is also known as '*al-Ahmar*' because of his clan name, *Banu al-Ahmar*. Hence, the Nasrid dynasty is also referred to as Banu Nasr or **Banu al-Ahmar**.

You can see this here:

- *[The Spread of Islam Throughout the World](https://books.google.com.my/books?id=qVYT4Kraym0C&pg=PA476&dq=why%20was%20Muhammad%20I%20also%20known%20as%20Ibn%20al-A%E1%B8%A5mar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOjKjbtPbVAhUmTo8KHbG1C2IQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=why%20was%20Muhammad%20I%20also%20known%20as%20Ibn%20al-A%E1%B8%A5mar&f=false)*, edited by Idris El Hareir, Ravane Mbaye, and
- *[Histoire des Benou’l-Ahmar : rois de Grenade](https://ballandalus.wordpress.com/2017/06/09/french-translation-of-ibn-khalduns-history-of-the-nasrid-dynasty/)*, a 1899 French translation by Maurice Gaudefroy-Demombynes of *[ibn Khaldun](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/imo3/ibn.htm)’s* History of the Nasrid Dynasty

Comment: I am already aware of the clan's name (see question description). If you argue that ibn al-Ahmar's name is because of the clan name (and not the other way around), then can you also explain why the clan was known as "Banu al-Ahmar"?

Comment: Nope, I cannot say _why_ (difficult to for a name) but is clearly their genealogy of [**Nasr**](http://referenceworks.brillonline.com/entries/encyclopaedia-of-islam-2/ahmar-banu-DUM_0195) -  Brill's Referenceworks link

Comment: And no, I am **not** arguing anything. Just presenting the info. You will know if I argue.

Answer (score 1):

The Banū l-Aḥmar have their name quite simply from a real or fictitious ancestor with the name (or nick name) al-Aḥmar “the ruddy one”.

Comment: It would be great to see some quotes and sources that tell the story in your answer.